# Hide button menu strip when I open another form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a great application with an initial form. This form has a menu strip with four "buttons" like this:

[My Form with menu strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVKt4.png)

This main form contains another form with more applications. **What I want to do is when I open another form (application) I want to hide only the menu strip item called "Cambiar Empresa"**.

What I have thought is to make visibility false when I am in another form, but I cannot call this form because there is a problem of circular dependence.

How could I do this?

**EDIt**:

The *second form* is in the pink line and the *main form* is in the blue line:

[Estructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9ZZj.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You''ll have to either change your app's architecture so that you avoid circular dependency or what it comes to my mind as a workaround is to declare some `public static bool showCambiarEmpresa = false` that would be accessible to both sides of your circular dependency sides so that one can set it and other can read it.

Comment: Ty faithfull. But this variable I would have to do it in the main form but I can't access there with the other form, right? @faithfull

Comment: Well, to be able to access this variable both the 'main' form and the 'other' form would need to have a common parent, e.i. they should somehow both inherit from a class that is defining this `static` variable.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code where you are facing this issue

Comment: I don't know about your implementation however, if the 'other' form is instantiated from the 'main' form, then why not just passing some `flag` that would tell to your new form to hide that button?

Comment: Ty guys for your help. I've updated the post with where are the main and second form.

Comment: Your edit doesn't mean much because C# is object-oriented programming language and your project structure does not relate to the way your class-object constructs were implemented. Please provide us with a concrete, yet minimalistic, working example of your code.

Comment: so the best would be hide this button from the child form? or child tell to parent form to hide this strip item in his strip menu? @faithfull

Comment: I don't understand what triggers the opening of that new form, is it a button click in your main form or something else?

Comment: Yes, is a button click in my main form @faithfull ... I've been thinking, could be an option try to do this with ActiveForm?

Comment: Oh, I haven't worked with WinForms ever so I can't tell you... My perception is to pass a flag from parent to child form where you would tell the child form not to show the `CambiarEmpresa`.

Comment: @greatWallace if you find any of the comments beneficial to you, please up-vote. Gracias ;)

Comment: @faithfull thank you for your information Faithfull, i'm new here, if some of this comments is beneficial for me i will up-vote but I am still trying to fix this problem :|

Comment: About your question, I want to confirm again. Do you hide the button successfully? Do you problems about how to call another project form? If so, why not create the same form in your current project?